# Mule ESB: how to filter emails based on subject or sender?

Tags: email, filter, header, esb, mule

I am new to Mule 3.3 and I am trying to use it to retrieve emails from a POP3 server and download the CSV attachments if the sender field and subject field contain certain keywords. I have used the example provided on Mulesoft website and I have successfully managed to scan my inbox for new emails and only download CSV attachments. However, I am now stuck because I can't figure out how to filter emails by subject and sender fields.

Doing some research I have come across a *message-property-filter pattern* tag that can be applied to an endpoint, but I am not sure exactly to which endpoint to apply it, incoming or outgoing. Neither approach seems to work and I can't find a decent example showing how to use this tag. The basic algorithm I want to implement is as follows:

```
if email is from "Bob"
  if attachment of type "CSV"
    then download CSV attachment

if email subject field contains "keyword"
  if attachment of type CSV
    then download CSV attachment
```

Here's the Mule xml I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:pop3s="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pop3s" xmlns:pop3="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pop3" 
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" 
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pop3s http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pop3s/current/mule-pop3s.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pop3 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pop3/current/mule-pop3.xsd ">


<expression-transformer expression="#[attachments-list:*.csv]" 
   name="returnAttachments" doc:name="Expression">
</expression-transformer>

<pop3s:connector name="POP3Connector" 
    checkFrequency="5000" 
    deleteReadMessages="false" 
    defaultProcessMessageAction="RECENT" 
    doc:name="POP3" 
    validateConnections="true">
</pop3s:connector>

<file:connector name="fileName" doc:name="File">
    <file:expression-filename-parser />
</file:connector>

<flow name="incoming-orders" doc:name="incoming-orders">

    <pop3s:inbound-endpoint user="my_username" 
        password="my_password" 
        host="pop.gmail.com" 
        port="995" 
        transformer-refs="returnAttachments"
        doc:name="GetMail" 
        connector-ref="POP3Connector" 
        responseTimeout="10000"/>
    <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>

    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>

    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/attachments" 
        outputPattern="#[function:datestamp].csv"
        doc:name="File" responseTimeout="10000"> 
        <expression-transformer expression="payload.inputStream"/>
        <message-property-filter pattern="from=(.*)(bob@email.com)(.*)" caseSensitive="false"/>
    </file:outbound-endpoint>           
</flow>
```

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Mule! A few month ago I implemented a similar proejct for a customer. I take a look at your flow, let´s start refactoring.

- Remove the transformer-refs="returnAttachments" from inbound-endpoint
- Add the following elements to your flow

  ```
  <pop3:inbound-endpoint ... />
  <custom-filter class="com.benasmussen.mail.filter.RecipientFilter"> 
      <spring:property name="regex" value=".*bob.bent@.*" />
  </custom-filter>
  <expression-transformer>
      <return-argument expression="*.csv" evaluator="attachments-list" />
  </expression-transformer>
  <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter" />
  ```
- Add my RecipientFilter as java class to your project. All messages will be discard if they don't match to the regex pattern.

  ```
  package com.benasmussen.mail.filter;

  import java.util.Collection;
  import java.util.Set;
  import java.util.regex.Pattern;      
  import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
  import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Initialisable;
  import org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException;
  import org.mule.api.routing.filter.Filter;
  import org.mule.config.i18n.CoreMessages;
  import org.mule.transport.email.MailProperties;

  public class RecipientFilter implements Filter, Initialisable
  {
      private String regex;
      private Pattern pattern;

      public boolean accept(MuleMessage message)
      {
          String from = message.findPropertyInAnyScope(MailProperties.FROM_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, null);
          return isMatch(from);
      }

      public void initialise() throws InitialisationException
      {
          if (regex == null)
          {
              throw new InitialisationException(CoreMessages.createStaticMessage("Property regex is not set"), this);
          }
          pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
      }

      public boolean isMatch(String from)
      {
          return pattern.matcher(from).matches();
      }

      public void setRegex(String regex)
      {
          this.regex = regex;
      }
  }
  ```

The mule expression framework is powerful, but in some use cases I prefer my own business logic.

#### Improvment

- Use application properties (mule-app.properties) > [mule documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Using+Parameters+in+Your+Configuration+Files)

#### Documentation

- [MailProperties](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.transports/mule-transport-email/3.3.0/org/mule/transport/email/MailProperties.java?av=f) shows you all available message properties (EMail)
- Take a look at the [mule schema doc](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.0/schemadocs/) to see all available elements
- Incoming payload (mails, etc) are transported by an [DefaultMuleMessage](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule/mule-core/3.3.0/org/mule/DefaultMuleMessage.java/) (Payload, Properties, Attachments)

Answer (score 8):

To help you, here are two configuration bits:

- The following filter accepts only messages where `fromAddress` is 'Bob' and where subject contains 'keyword':

  ```
  <expression-filter
      expression="#[message.inboundProperties.fromAddress == 'Bob' || message.inboundProperties.subject contains 'keyword']" />
  ```
- The following transformer extracts all the attachments whose names end with '.csv':

  ```
  <expression-transformer
      expression="#[($.value in message.inboundAttachments.entrySet() if $.key ~= '.*\\.csv')]" />
  ```

Comment: Thanks @DavidDossot. The functionality I am trying to implement right now would create separate directories named after email senders. If the sender is "bob" then a directory /bob is created into which the attachment would be downloaded. Since I am new to Mule, one way of doing this that is obvious to me would be to use a custom filter that would have a java class creating the directories. However, I am not sure how the name of that created directory would then get passed and set in the file:outbound-endpoint. Maybe you can shed some light on the matter and suggest an easier approach? Thanks