# Custom filter in Mule

Tags: java, mule

In my mule project I have to receive a json data and create create a java object with the json data and then I need a filter wich decides to send an email or whatever only if the data stored on the java object fits with some rules(for example send information if variable a >10 or something like that) but I don't know how to make a custom filter.Can anyone guide me  or whow me any tutorial?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read the http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to learn how to ask a question here.

Comment: All of this can be achieved using filters that mule provides, there is no need for custom filter.

Comment: You can find an example around custom filter

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102207/mule-esb-how-to-filter-emails-based-on-subject-or-sender

Answer (score 1):

you can create your custom Filter class by implementing `org.mule.api.routing.filter.Filter` interface. You need to put your implementation code in `boolean accept(MuleMessage message);` method

you can define the same in mule configuration file by doing this

```
<filter ref="filterBean">
```

and bean is defined as follows

```
<bean id="filterBean"  class="QualifiedNameOfCustomBeanClass">
```

hope it helps!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your Custom filter using **java** class, please find the **example** as follows :-

```
<message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="true"  doc:name="Message">
    <custom-filter class="com.test.CustomSchemaValidationFilter.CustomSchemaValidationFilterWithTrace"/>
 </message-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link which should help you writing a custom filter. If you still have any issues, let us know.

[Mule ESB: how to filter emails based on subject or sender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102207/mule-esb-how-to-filter-emails-based-on-subject-or-sender)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this basis for creating a custom filter,

```
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.routing.filter.Filter;


public class CartonItemsFilter implements Filter{

   @Override
   public boolean accept(MuleMessage message) {

    return false;
   }

}
```